# Subdirectories in prompt?

Tags: macos, bash, ls, prompt

I'm working on making my prompt as useful as possible. Right now, it contains the date, time, and directory, along with a colored divider line so I can easily see where each batch of input starts.

I was wondering - would it be possible to make it so my prompt automatically listed a few files / folders in a subdirectory? It seems like it would make for a nice cheat sheet kind of thing... instead of typing <kbd>L</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> (I know, what a burden) and then getting the cheat sheet, I just automatically have it printed for me.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could just set up an alias?

```
cd() { builtin cd "$1" ; ls ; }
```

Code from https://superuser.com/a/355483/36744

Comment: That's an interesting thought, but the primary use I thought of was that I could see where I am immediately when I log in. Maybe I should stick an ls in my login script?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: Sounds like a reasonable approach

Comment: I added your alias plus an ls to my login script. I like this behavior - it should prove helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in adding further utility to your prompt (and generally make your terminal experience better), it may be worth thinking about switching from bash to zsh for your shell. Check out the themes at [oh my zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes) to see how creative people get with their prompts.

Beyond a better prompt though, the most useful thing I've found is [zsh syntax highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting) — it makes writing command line scripts in terminal *much* nicer.

Comment: That page certainly has some interesting stuff on it. I attempted to install zsh one time. It didn't work at all for me. I spent the rest of the day just trying to get bash to work again. As nice as zsh looks, I don't think it's worth my spending another day trying to figure it out. I'm a developer - I don't spend enough time in the terminal for it to be worth it for me.

Comment: Just discovered I can actually pretty easily reproduce at least most (maybe all) of the cool things from those zsh themes just by using UTF-8 in bash... IE, by using UTF-8 box drawing characters I can outline parts of the text the way I want. I suspect if I look through all the special characters I'll see how to reproduce every part of those themes.

Comment: I've got some notes from when I first installed it back in January and I also ran into some issues. Not sure if you experienced the same, but `brew install zsh` followed by _not_ changing **/etc/zshenv** to **/etc/zprofile** is what ended up doing the trick for me. zsh has tons of nice stuff going for it beyond just looking pretty... sure it was a bit of a pain to setup but I haven't looked back since :)